# separated semicolon in fields splid and each

Tags: mysql

my problem in mysql,

i have 4 column name or field. My columns name are:

```
**bimages              dimages                   simages**

a.jpg;b.jpg;c.jpg      a1.jpg;b1.jpg;c1.jpg      a2.jpg;b2.jpg;c2.jpg
```

I want splitted by ; (semicolon) and each results.

for example:

```
bimages  - dimages - simages (Field Name)
a.jpg      a1.jpg    a2.jpg
b.jpg      b1.jpg    b2.jpg
c.jpg      c1.jpg    c2.jpg
```

UPDATE**

i want to result in a column or Field. No it isn't PHP

```
**images
a.jpg
b.jpg
c.jpg
a1.jpg
b1.jpg
c1.jpg
a2.jpg
b2.jpg
c2.jpg
...**
```

Comment: Do you need to get the result in PHP?

Comment: In your case you could use the REPLACE() function to replace the semicolons with newlines, although it would be helpful to know what this is ultimately for, because there's likely a better way to do it.

Comment: How do I get a new line in mysql? thanks for your reply

Comment: MySQL uses C-style string syntax, including \n for new lines. By the way, if you don't need it for PHP, you should think about removing the PHP tag for the question :)

Answer (score 1):

In php you use the function explode. You give the delimiter (; in your case) and the string itself. As a result you get an array.

```
$bimagesArray = explode(";", $bimages);
$dimagesArray = explode(";", $dimages);
$simagesArray = explode(";", $simages);
```

Comment: Hey sorry, I can't help you with MySQL, think there is not a premade function for this in MySQL so I guess you have to work with substring etc. But I'm not an expert in MySQL